# Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)---Why is "object" not capitalised?

Tags: c#, .net

"object" here should refer to the "Object" class. As with all class identifiers in the .NET framework, it is supposed to be capitalised although not case sensitive. But I realise in c# it is not capitalised by default. Why is that? Is it because C# is modelled after Java which had some sort of non capitalised object class? I can't remember Java syntax already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object` is just a C# keyword that refers to the `System.Object` class. In just the same way, `string` is a keyword that refers to the `System.String` class. You can use the capitalized and non-capitalized versions interchangably, but it helps to highlight that these two classes are treated "specially" by the C# language (in that `object` is the default class that all classes inherit from, and `string` is the type of "xyz" constant expressions).

Also, C# is case-sensitive. `EventArgs` is a different class to `eventargs` (say).

Comment: Brilliant. This issue has made me uncomfortable till now